Как отследить на какое письмо поступил ответ exchangelib
Несколько человек отвечают на почту, иногда возникают сложности в понимании на что ответили, а что осталось без ответа
Пробывал сохранять item.text_body и сравнивать его с ответом на него
if item.text_body in saved_msg:
    print("Done")

После понял что много лишнего, сделал item.text_body.split("mailto:")[1]
Так же не получил желаемого результата
Возможно есть какой-то аргумент который передает к примеру item.message_id письма на которое был ответ или что-то в этом роде?
К сожалению не нашел подобной информации в документации

Извините, я сам нашел решение.
Распечатал item ответа и начал искать item.message_id оригинального сообщения, среди других аргументов был замечен in_reply_to='<f0ae9be2e1c747a5b42c741552f49ab2@outlook.com>
Распечатал item.in_reply_to в сообщении ответа, и он совпал с оригиналом.

Зачем же вы извиняетесь? Хорошо, что нашли решение. Можете, заодно, отметить свой ответ как принятый.
